# Why isn't there a non-destructive version of std::remove?

Tags: c++, std

An algorithm that "removes" elements in a range non-destructively by moving them to the end and not preserving their order while preserving the order of the elements not "removed" could be useful, and can run in linear time with no auxiliary space. Implementation is simple:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator nd_remove_if(ForwardIterator head, ForwardIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    using std::swap;

    ForwardIterator swap_head = head;
    while(head != last)
    {
        while(swap_head != last && !pred(*swap_head))
            ++swap_head;
        if(swap_head == last)
            break;

        if(!pred(*head))
            swap(*head, *swap_head);
        else
            ++swap_head;
        ++head;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Basically, it is a partition that would be stable for the left side but not for the right. Its advantage over `std::stable_partition` is that not requiring the right side to be stable allows a linear time implementation without extra space.

Why isn't this in the standard library? I feel it is useful enough and general enough to fit in there.

Comment: `std::remove` will use move assignment if available. Is that what you mean by "non-destructive"?

Comment: @NeilKirk What I mean by non-destructive is not leaving the removed values in an unspecified state, i.e. they are guaranteed to be the same as before, just at the end and not necessarily in the same order. Am I making sense?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what use case do you have for this where neither `stable_partition` nor `remove_if` are better suited? I suspect it's very specific, and if it was considered at all, that's the main reason it's not part of the standard, but perhaps your use case will turn out to be far more general than I am imagining.

Comment: @PiotrS. `std::partition` makes no guarantees about stability. My whole point is to keep the stability of the non-removed elements, as guaranteed by `std::remove`, while also leaving the removed elements in a specified state.

Comment: @hvd I guess I haven't really thought that through much. The idea of a general algorithm hit me when someone told me about an interview question they had with Google: to move the zeros to the end of a container in linear time while preserving the order of the others. Neither `std::remove` nor `std::stable_partition` are fits for this use case, as `std::remove` doesn't guarantee the elements at the end will be zeros, and `std::stable_partition` either uses extra space or doesn't take linear time. I just generalized the problem.

Comment: @PiotrS. I stated the advantage over `std::stable_partition` in the question. That requires either auxiliary space or linearithmic time, while my algorithm requires neither and is always linear. It discards the requirement that the right side must preserve the order, which allows for the improvement in bounds.

Comment: Ah, yes, I suppose that's a good example. If you need to preserve order, you'd use `stable_partition`, except that when all values in one of the partitions are known to be equivalent, that does more work than necessary.

Comment: @hvd Except that, if I'm not mistaken, `std::stable_partition` will require either auxiliary space proportional to input or will take linearithmic time. I was trying to avoid those performance limitations basically by doing the same thing as a stable partition except not requiring the right side to be stable after the algorithm is performed.

Comment: @mebob Hence the "except that when [...] that does more work than necessary" in my comment. :) I was agreeing with your conclusion that `stable_partition` would not be the best approach here.

Comment: @hvd Oh, my mistake :) Though I think my algorithm also is better in any case where, for some reason, stability is required on the left but not on the right. I guess that is sort of a narrow range of use cases that would mostly be filled with exactly what you said.

Comment: Basically, what you want is a version of `std::remove` that uses `swap` instead of a copy- or move-assignment. If you look at the [archetypes for remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), and simply replace `*first++ = std::move(*i);` with `swap(*first++, *i);` (or, using iter_swap), you get want you want, order preserved on the left and valid objects on the right (in reverse order.. I guess you could get a linear-time no-extra-space stable-partition by reversing the right range afterwards). I guess this could have been part of the standard algorithms.

Comment: @MikaelPersson That sounds like exactly what I'm asking for. I'm surprised they DON'T have it.

Comment: Never mind my comment about the right range having reverse order... that's definitely not the case, it was too late to edit when I realized that.